# How do we use .so libraries in Titanium module?

Tags: android, titanium

I am trying to include a shared object library (`.so`) in my Titanium module for Android.

I have included the two `.so` files in the following folders:

```
android/lib/armeabi
android/lib/armeabi-v7a
android/lib/x86
android/jni/armeabi
android/jni/armeabi-v7a
android/jni/x86
android/jniLibs/armeabi
android/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a
android/jniLibs/x86
```

I'm getting a message in my console when I try to build my module:

```
 [exec] Android NDK:     This is likely to result in incorrect builds. Try using LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES
 [exec] Android NDK:     or LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES instead to list the library dependencies of the
 [exec] Android NDK:     current module
```

Overall my build is not happening, but what does this message tell me? I have tried all of the following in my `Android.mk` files:

```
include $(LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES)
include $(LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES)
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

But Titanium still generates an `Android.mk` with `include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)`.

Has anyone successfully used an `.so` library in a Titanium module?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this link provides the references you are looking for: [gist with shorts steps](https://gist.github.com/omorandi/6241406)

Here's the contents:

> From: http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/121573/how-do-i-use-so-library-in-module
>
> Place .so files in mymodule/lib/armeabi
>
> Add this to build.xml:

```
<target name="post.jar">
  <copy todir="${libs}">
    <fileset dir="lib">
      <include name="**/*.so"/>
    </fileset>
  </copy>
</target>
```

Run: *jar tf dist/com.example.mymodule-android-0.1.zip* to verify that the desired library files have been added to the module.